# Copying from lstlisting converted to pdf

Tags: code

I use pdflatex to convert my tex file, and I use lots of lstlisting due to the technical nature of the document. The main issue I have is in making the text copy/paste friendly. Please see the screenshot attached, for the #include and #define in C code, it looks like the text gets selected and copied as a column rather than as a line.

[image]

It leads to broken code when pasting it, with the first lines being #include only, and the lines after that being the name of the packages being including, making the code unusable.

Is there a way to force the copy of text to be on a line basis?

If it can be of any help, here is the style used for my lstlisting:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Bash,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
  upquote=true,
  backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray},
  xleftmargin=10pt,
  xrightmargin=10pt,
  framexleftmargin=10pt,
  framexrightmargin=10pt,
  keepspaces=true
}
```

Comment: Wellcome to TeX.SE! Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: Evince in GNU/Linux, and this is for an exam with a focus on GNU/Linux, so most likely the reviewers will be using evince as well.

Comment: Probably quite dependent on the PDF viewer. I would try omitting the syntax highlighting colors, maybe use `fancyvrb` instead of `listings`. Also, would it not be more straightforward to just distribute the listed sources as plain text files? That would be easier to use than copying and pasting ...